# Flash Professional CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

When I save the file, as I need it as a swf file to be able to put in Dreamweaver. The files saved but when I open the document its blank. Does anyone know why or how to solve this issue

I have tried saving it in different formats but it still wont show up, I also thought it might be due to the size, maybe I didn't have enough memory for it but I've now moved almost everything off my hard drive now, so there's plenty of space.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue or it there a different way to save it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your issue. Are you trying to embed an swf file into a html page using dreamweaver. If so, what HTML code are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm inserting the saved animation into dreamweaver (adobe dreamweaver CS5)its accepting it but its not playing, it shows up as a blank document in live view and when previewing it in browser.